# Is curvature additive?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, curvature

So I'm having such a problem:

There is given parametric curve, let's call it L. The curve is then slightly deformed so that there are perpendicular defomations given by the function g(s) along the L. What I need is the difference in curvature between deformed and undeformed state of the curve. Will this be simply the curvature of the function g(s), which then, under assumption of small deformations, could be approximated by its 2nd derivative?

The problem, simplifying a bit, is about calculating the elastic energy of deformed curved beam.

Answer (score 0):

The variation of the curvature, for a small perturbation of the curve, typically yields a Laplace-Beltrami operator. To be more specific, one would have to know what is the functional exactly and what is the dimension of the ambient space.

See this paper for instance: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00565403/en